# Como utilizar múltiplas Threads para executar um build Mais Rápido no Maven

Tags: java, maven, multithreading, paralelismo, integração-contínua

O que o **Maven** oferece em termos de **paralelismo** para execução de *builds*?

Se eu executo um *build* em uma máquina com mais de um *processador*, como posso tirar vantagem de mais recursos para o processamento?

Qual é a expectativa de melhoria da performance que podemos esperar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir do Maven 3.x podemos requisitar que builds sejam executados com múltiplas Threads.

**Como?**

utilizando a opcão **-T** [numero de threads] 
podemos definir quantas Threads desejamos para o build, assim como podemos determinar quantas por CPU

**Exemplos**

```
mvn -T 4 clean install # Builds with 4 threads
mvn -T 1C clean install # 1 thread per cpu core
mvn -T 1.5C clean install # 1.5 thread per cpu core
```

> Qual é a expectativa de melhoria da performance que podemos esperar?

Bom, isso pode variar dependendo da estrutura de seus projetos, mas as seguintes evidências foram obtidas:

- Melhoria de velocidade 20-50% é bastante comum.
- Se os testes de seus módulos forem distribuídos em módulos, existe grande possibilidade de ganho de performance, tendo um único projeto de testes, tende a diminuir a performance, a menos que seja executado um outro plugin do surefire em paralelo.

Fontes:

http://jknowledgecenter.blogspot.com/2015/06/maven-tips-and-tricks.html

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3